# Razor code to programmatically hide global menu items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm an experienced .NET programmer, but I'm new to this whole web programming thing.  My ASP.NET MVC website has a global layout that includes some content (menu links at the top of the page) that I want to hide under conditions that are detected dynamically by controller code.

My inclination -- the simple approach that uses the tools I've learned about thus far -- is to shove a Boolean HideGlobal value into the ViewBag, and to put the global markup in _Layout.cshtml that I want to hide inside of an @if (ViewBag.HideGlobal){} block.

I just want to know if this is the "proper" way to do it, or is there some Razor magic that I should be using for reasons that are not yet evident to me?

Comment: Depending on how you determine to show or hide the item you might want to set a ViewData item in an action filter (outside the controller).

Comment: If you shove a HideGlobal in view bag, you'll need to do so in every single action.

Comment: @Omar that's not true an `ActionFilter` means you can do it globally

Comment: @Lavinski - I was referring to Bob's approach.

Comment: @Omar right, in that case yeah

Comment: No, I don't need to do it in every action.  I can write: @if (ViewBag.HideMenu == null || !ViewBag.HideMenu) { <nav>...</nav> }

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS - but you'll need to set `ViewBag.HideMenu` in every action if you're going to do it in one action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dislike using the view model of the action outside of the view returned by the action. Using base view model for this scenario feels very clunky.

I believe it's cleaner and more obvious to just use a separate (child) action that contains the logic for specifying how the global menu should be displayed. This action returns the global menu view. Call that action from your layout page.

Or you can create an action for the entire header where the menu's state is determined -- or do an if/else to render a partial view of the global menu.

The example below encapsulates the needs of a header/global menu and offers a future proof way of changing your header/menu with minimal effect on your code infrastructure (base view model).

**~/Controllers/LayoutController.cs**

```
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Header()
    {
        var model = new HeaderViewModel();
        model.ShowGlobalMenu = ShowGobalMenu();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**~/Views/Layout/Header.cshtml**

```
@model HeaderViewModel
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<header>
    <a href="/">Home</a>

    @if(Model.ShowGlobalMenu)
    {
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
</header>
```

**~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <body>
        @Html.Action("Header", "Layout")

        <p>Stuff</p>
    </body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, especially Omar for the clear and concise example of using a child action (which I've run across but never dug into how to use).  FWIW, I've decided to use a bit of everyone's suggestions.  Most of my pages have a static layout that either always does or does not want to hide the menu, but one page needs to make the decision on the fly. I'll decorate the pages with an action filter attribute that sets or clears ViewBag values that tell the child action how to create the header layout.

Answer (score 3):

What you've described (putting a bool into the ViewBag) will work fine.  But personally, I like the strongly-typed model experience, so when I want to have UI logic like what you're describing in the master/layout page (which is pretty much always), I prefer to put those flags into a base model that my other models inherit from.

```
public class BaseModel
{
     public bool HideGlobal { get; set; }
}
```

And at the top of the _Layout.cshtml page, I specify that I'm expecting a BaseModel:

```
@model Company.Project.BaseModel
```

Other views can, of course, require other model types, but if they're using this layout, those model types should derive from BaseModel.

Finally, when I want to check the flag, rather than having a mysterious, undocumented field in the ViewBag, I've got the lovely intellisense and feel-good strongly-typed member of the model:

```
@if (!Model.HideGlobal)
{
    <div>...</div>
}
```

Edit:  I should probably add that it's often nice to also have a base controller whose job it is to populate the fields in BaseModel.  Mine usually look like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result != null)
        {
            var baseModel = result.Model as BaseModel;
            if (baseModel != null)
            {
                //Set HideGlobal and other BaseModel properties here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First answer here, be gentle :-)

Comment: An example of .net crying out for mixins...menus in a base model feels forced

Comment: This type of thing is usually based on user permissions which would be much better in an Action Filter instead of the base controller. Yes you would have to use the ViewData or ViewBag but it's really not part of the view it's higher up in _layout.cshtml

Comment: After some thought, I probably prefer Omar's answer to mine for this particular menu example, where having a child action makes everything more neat than I have it here.  Although personally, I do like the base model for other scenarios, like advertisement data that often impacts several parts of the layout that work together and aren't as intuitively isolated.

Comment: Ok... If I use the strongly-typed BaseModel approach then EVERY view needs to have an @model directive whose argument is BaseModel or a subclass thereof.  That means I can't just fabricate a list of items to be displayed and give the view "@model IEnumerable<Item>".  I'd need to create a model that inherits from BaseModel for every scenario I encounter.  OTOH, if I use ViewBag then I can just test for (ViewBag.HideGlobal == null || !ViewBag.HideGlobal), and I don't need to set ViewBag.HideGlobal in controller code unless I need to.

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS, for the somewhat rare situation where my model is something really simple like an IEnumerable<T> and I don't want to bother creating its own model class, I have a generic version of BaseModel, BaseModel<T> with a property of type T named "Data."  This allows me the benefits of the BaseModel approach without having to make a separate model class for every view.  However, I usually avoid using that class because I find I nearly always need some other piece of data down the road and I'd rather just start off with a proper model class.

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS, there's nothing magic about the base controller, it's just a class that inherits from Controller that all my controllers derive from.  The overridden method in my post checks to see if the model being passed to the view is a BaseModel, and if it is, fills in the data in the BaseModel.

Although there are other good ways of accomplishing all this, I kind of enjoy the symmetry of having a BaseModel, _Layout.cshtml, and BaseController all kind of doing the same jobs that my "normal" Models, Views, and Controllers are doing.

Comment: @Jared Phelps I really don't like the sound of BaseModel<T> to hold global state. It has complicated your design a lot and seems like a recipe for abuse especially with multiple developers. Could you not just make a wrapper for View Data using something like a HtmlHelper if intellisense is that important?

Comment: @Lavinski I understand the potential for abuse of BaseModel<T>, but I'm not sure it has complicated my design significantly.  It's a quick and dirty method of doing something that is by its nature, quick and dirty (using a class as a model that wasn't written specifically for the job).  So I don't think I've introduced anything that wasn't already there. The suggestion to put it all in a wrapper accessed with HtmlHelper is interesting, but it seems like a fair amount of mess for little benefit (particularly when you're dealing with larger models than the one described in the OP).

Answer (score 2):

This type of thing is usually based on user permissions which would be much better in an Action Filter instead of the base controller.

Yes you would have to use the `ViewData` or `ViewBag` but it's really not part of the view/model it's higher up in your _layout.cshtml

**Action Filter**

```
public class UserAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
        var hasAccessToMenu = /* Code */;

        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["GlobalVisible"] = hasAccessToMenu;
    }
}
```

**View (_layout.cshtml)**

```
@if(ViewData["GlobalVisible"])
{
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

This gives you the advantage of separating this logic out of the controller and because it's global that's important.

*Also I've used `ViewData` in my example but using `ViewBag` is just as good.*

Comment: Actually, in my case my need to hide the global content really is determined by business logic in a controller.  My app is a glorified interview, where one person sets up the interview (call this Step 1), then hands the computer to the person who will take the interview (call this Step 2).  In Step 2, I don't want the person in front of the computer to be able to leave the app, so when the Interview controller determines that the interview has progressed to Step 2 then I want to hide the menus.

Comment: @Bob.at.SBS then you may want to update your question, or ask a more specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I put this at the top of my Razor page:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
```

But keep in mind that hides _Layout.cshtml and everything it has so one must create local repsonsive CSS and Jquery.

Also, one can use the RouteData.Values["page"] to identify and act on page inside _Layout.cshtml

```
 var pageRoute = "";
 pageRoute = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"].ToString();
             
if(pageRoute=="/Courses_New/Index")
{
//yada yada
}
```